# Getting 'Error: Could not find or load main class' even though class is present in jar

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

Getting 'Error: Could not find or load main class' even though class is present in jar

We have a command line utility in our project which refers to our project jar and is run using an sh file. It used to to work without any problem in our previous release. Suddenly it has stopped working. Even though the jar is included in classpath, when the command line utility is executed, getting error 'Error: Could not find or load main class'.
The jar is created by building the project with ant 1.9.6 and java 8.

Following is the ant task which creates the jar-

```
<target name="jar-all" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="build/jar/${ant.project.name}-all.jar" basedir="build/classes/">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="build/lib/" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/" includes="*.jar"/>
        </jar>
</target>
```

I have tried ant jar task zip64mode thinking size of jar file may be an issue. It did not make any difference.

Sh file which sets classpath for the command line utility (runprog.sh)-

```
#!/bin/bash

DISTDIR=/usr/share/deploy/tools/tools-dist/
APPCTX="applicationContext-tools.localhost.xml"
TOMCATDIR=/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/
_FXLCP=""
#/usr/share/java/groovy-all.jar
for d in "$TOMCATDIR $DISTDIR"; do
        for f in `find ${d} -name \*.jar`; do
                _FXLCP="${_FXLCP}:${f}"
        done
done
_FXLCP="${_FXLCP}:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/servlet-api.jar"

_CWD=`pwd`
cd $DISTDIR
java -classpath $_FXLCP ${1} ${APPCTX} ${@:2}
cd $_CWD
```

Sh file which is used to run the utilty-

```
#!/bin/bash

RUNCMD=/usr/share/deploy/tools/runprog.sh

echo "Select from the following tools:"
echo "  1) Searcher"
echo "  2) Duplicator"

echo -n "Enter a number: "
read _NUM

if [ "X${_NUM}" == "X1" ]; then
  ${RUNCMD} au.com.tools.Searcher
elif [ "X${_NUM}" == "X2" ]; then
  ${RUNCMD} au.com.tools.Duplicator
else
  echo "Bad selection"
fi
```

Read on ant website that for building java version 1.8 code, it was recommended to use ant version 1.10.x. Currently we use ant version 1.9.6. Unistalled ant 1.9.6 and installed 1.10.3 and built the jar. Still getting same error.
Also tried comparing the jars of releases where it work and where it doesn't work, did not find any issue.

Java - 1.8
ant - 1.9.6
Platform - Ubuntu 16.04
JAR size - 70.7 MB
Exploded JAR size - 161.1 MB

Comment: Share the class which has the main method.

Comment: It is a menu based command line utility. There is an sh file in which the menu is defined which takes number as input. The utlity is run using this sh file. On every menu option selected, a class is called, which has main method in it.